# What is $\lambda$ in Maxwell's EM diffusion equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, diffusion

I am reading an old paper from the 1970s regarding a line current EM induction. In the paper they say that (under certain assumptions), Maxwell's equations can be simplified to a diffusion equation of the form:

$$\nabla^2E_y = i\omega\mu\sigma E_y$$

They then go on to say that "employing the method of separation of variables we assume that $E_y(x,z) = X(x)Z(z)$ and find that the diffusion equation is satisfied by terms of the form:

$$E_y(x,z) = e^{\pm\theta z}\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{cos}(\lambda x)\\ 
\mathrm{sin}(\lambda x)
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\theta^2 = i\omega\mu\sigma + \lambda^2$

Can someone explain how they got to this results and what does $\lambda$ physically represent?

Thanks.

Comment: remember that for a harmonic wave $\mathfrak j \omega E_y=\frac{\partial E_y}{\partial t}$ so it is a diffusion equation for $E_y$ in a dissipating medium with $\mu \sigma$ representing the diffusion coefficient. In the formula you quoted $\lambda$ is the spatial wavenumber that is the wavelength  is $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ in the direction $x$ and $\theta$ is the exponential attenuation rate along $z$.